# ができます meaning on this sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice

長い時間働き続けるより、少し休んだほうがいい **仕事ができますよ**。

I think I understand the overall meaning, which is. *Rather than to work long hour, it's better to take a little break.*

But, I wasn't sure what 仕事ができます doing in the end of the sentence...

I understand it as **can work/finish work** It doesn't make sense to me currently...

If it's written like this, I can understand it... 仕事のことは 長い時間働き続けるより、少し休んだほうがいい.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence can be split as follows:

> 長い時間働き続けるより、 / 少し休んだほうが / いい仕事ができますよ。

So the fixed phrase ～ほうがいい is not the case.

As you might know, いい仕事ができます means "can do good work."

The translation would be:

> You can do the better work if you have a little break rather than work for a long time (*without taking a break*).

Comment: Ah, it's not the fixed ほうがいい. that's make sense... Thank you so much for clearing that up...

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it as "Rather than continuing to work for a long time, you can do better work if you take a little break." The いい仕事ができます part is the "can do better work" part of my above translation. Literally "いい仕事ができます" is "can do good work," but the ほうが is a comparative form, which is why "good" becomes "better".